# How to use Multiple Subview as Cover flow For IPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uipagecontrol, coverflow

[image]

I am working on Ipad application.In this application i want to add 15 subviews on my MainClass.Xib.
As my screen shot show that when i click on any subview its zoom out .my question is little bit  related to coverflow,but problem for me is that how can i add all these subview at mainview.xib and then using all behave these like cover flow.all these subview get some data from server.so can any one guide me how can i do this.Any help will be 
Appriated.Thanx